# Gnuplot - difference of column as x value

Tags: function, plot, gnuplot

I have three-column file and I would like to plot a graph, where x value is difference of two first columns (second minus first) and y value is third column. Does anyone know, what is the easiest way to do that?

I tried

```
 plot "data.txt" using 1:($2-$1) 2:($3)
```

but that doesn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
plot "data.txt" using ($2-$1):($3)
```

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thank you! I am new to gnuplot so I am still learning basics.